# How to put a database with data in SD card only once-when the application is installed

Tags: android

I have a database which contains data. How is it possible to put the database in SD card only once? i mean -while it is being installed?

And also want some pictures to be pushed too.

Help me out please.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `SharedPreferences`

```
private static final String FIRST_RUN = "first_run";
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences();

//Assume true if the key does not yet exist
if (prefs.getBoolean(FIRST_RUN, true)) {

    //Do your database operations
    ..............................................
} else {
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    edit.putBoolean(FIRST_RUN, false);
    edit.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just set one `shared preference` at first activity like splash of your app `with Boolean` value of false and do your work with database whatever u want in that condition after that set it with value true then it will not call that function until unless you re-install it or just not clear your data forcibly.

Comment: cant understand what u want to do with picture like if u also want to do same with picture also then do in that boolean condition itself dude